# ruby def function code not working

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax-error

Correct this code, so that the greet function returns the expected value.

```
class Person

  def initialize(name, other_name)

    @name = name

    @other_name = other_name

  end



  def greet(@other_name, @name)

    "Hi #{@other_name}, my name is #{@name}"

  end

end
```

Comment: What's the expected value? Your `greet` param names should *not* have `@` signs, and you don't need them anyway since you're interpolating instance variables. Also, when your code has an error you should post it.

Comment: I agree, you should add more detail when asking a question. The way it is worded makes it seem like a homework assignment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Correct this code"? Let's consider what Stack Overflow is: We help you debug problems with your code after you've given us the appropriate needed information. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and see if you've done that.

Answer (score 3):

You could rewrite it as:

```
class Person 
  def initialize(name, other_name)
    @name = name
    @other_name = other_name
  end

  def greet
    "Hi #{@other_name}, my name is #{@name}"
  end
end

c = Person.new("Sam", "Ruby")

2.1.0 :073 > c.greet
 => "Hi Ruby, my name is Sam"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables are stored in the class' instance, you don't need to pass them as arguments:

```
def greet()

    "Hi #{@other_name}, my name is #{@name}"

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the @ signs from the greet method. Arguments cannot be instance variables.